# Как растянуть картинку на весь экран?

Tags: html

Как растянуть картинку на весь экран, если я прописываю вот этот HTML код

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Trancitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Словарь терминов</title>
    </head>
    **<body background="img/image.jpg"  align="center" width="250" height="150">**
        <center><h1>Словарь терминов</h1></center>
```

У меня экран 1280x800.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**CSS3:**

```css
body {
        background: url(img/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

[Ещё варианты](http://sitear.ru/material/css-background-rastyanut).

Comment: Если в пути к картинке содержатся пробелы — `url(img/test image.jpg)` — следует поступить, как предписывает [данный комментарий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/96746/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD/494978?noredirect=1#comment593233_494978). Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло

Answer (score -1):

```
<body background="img/image.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Comment: не сработает если реальная ширина картинки будет меньше ширины окна браузера.

Answer (score -1):

Важно не забывать кавычки ставить: `background: url("img/image.jpg")`, иначе на экранах с некоторым разрешением внизу может появляться "полоса"— опускается самая верхняя часть фоновой картинки. [image]

Comment: Вы уверены? можно и без кавычек писать, это роли не играет, а чтобы фон не повторялся просто добавить нужно no-repeat

Comment: @soledar10, да, ибо таким образом лично разрешил проблему на своём сайте. Раньше нижняя часть его страниц выглядела на моём мониторе так:


![1](https://i.gyazo.com/beb1d767fbf26ab8b8980262f5d458e9.png)
![2](https://i.gyazo.com/c844c27de7e1b0898a3d02ef8227b4e6.png)


Если надо, могу html-страницы скинуть, проверьте на [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) с кавычками и без. Спасибо.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vLvrzh2x/ без разницы есть кавычки или нет

Comment: @soledar10, если изображение по ссылке, тоже не вижу изменений. Но если лежит в папке, похоже, кавычки приобретают значение:

[Отображение с кавычками](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//kristinita.ru/with_quotes.html&w=1024&h=768&a=1)  /
[Отображение без кавычек](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//kristinita.ru/without_quotes.html&w=1024&h=768&a=1)  /
[Код с кавычками](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/with_quotes.html)  /
[Код без кавычек](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/without_quotes.html)  /

Спасибо.

Comment: P. S. Некорректное отображение возникло из-за пробелов в именах картинок. Как и [в случае со шрифтами](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/svoi-shrift-na-stranitse#comment-2343695569) кавычки должно ставить при наличии пробелов, и необязательно, если их нет. От простановки всегда хуже не сделается. Спасибо.

Comment: Дело в том, что пробел не должен содержаться в адресе. Если он там есть, то помогает одно из следующих решений: 1. Честно заменить пробел  на `%20`. 2. Написать адрес в кавычках. 3. Экранировать пробел `\ `. В приведённых примерах фон с пробелом без кавычек вычёркивает всё css-свойство включая `no-repeat center center fixed`, однако, за счёт того, что у `body` есть устаревший атрибут `background` с той же картинкой, он всё же отображается. На самом деле, в нормальной ситуации фона в таком случае вообще не окажется.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PqN5F.jpg

Comment: @Qwertiy, может, напишете ответ на основе своего комментария? Этот удалю, поскольку в самом ответе не объясняется причина нежелательного поведения. Спасибо.